How do I search for geolocations stored in a Redis database that are contained within a polygon shape using Node.js?
I have multiple geolocations stored in a Redis database (version 7.2.4) in the following format:
GEOADD locations -46.63803300 (longitude) -23.53523600 (latitude) "270353275" (ID)
In Node.js (v13.5.0), I want to search for which geolocations are contained inside a given polygon.
Input: Geolocations of the polygon vertices are provided in the following format:
"bounds": [ { "lat": -23.534717280387206, "lng": -46.602115631103516 }, { "lat": -23.548251460987665, "lng": -46.623573303222656 }, ... ]
Output: IDs of the geolocations that are inside this polygon.
I'm trying to use the 'redis-redisearch' (^1.0.1) library with the 'ioredis' (v4.28.5) library in the following way:
`const redis = await getRedis() //returns new Redis client
redisearch(redis)
const results = await redis.ft_search(
"announces",
@location:{${polygon_query}},
"RETURN",
"1",
"@location"
)`
However, I'm receiving the error "redis.addCommand is not a function". How can I implement this functionality?"

Can you confirm which version of Redisearch you are using it? Assuming that it's Redis 7.2.4, you have to Search 2.8.x with the support of GEOSHAPES. Please see how to map it in your index https://redis.io/docs/latest/commands/ft.create/
Your polygons need to be on WKT notation and your query syntax will looks like:
FT.SEARCH index "@bounds:[CONTAINS $location] PARAMS 2 location "POINT(LON LAT)" RETURN 1 location DIALECT 3
More details you can find here in the documentation: https://redis.io/docs/latest/develop/interact/search-and-query/query/geo-spatial/

I'm using "redis-redisearch": "^1.0.1" in my node project. I also tried executing the FT.SEARCH command directly in the database, which is inside a Docker container, to test the params and results, but I'm receiving the error "ERR unknown command 'FT.SEARCH'". Other commands, as KEYS *, are working correctly.

Can you check the output of INFO MODULES command from the CLI? I'm not recognizing the version that you mentioned "redis-redisearch": "^1.0.1"

The modules list returned null from the CLI.
This is the library that I'm using, it was recommended on the Redis documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis-redisearch
When I use the redisearch(redis) command, I receive this "redis.addCommand is not a function" error.
